# Spawning Dominoes and keeping their rotations with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, rigid-body-simulation, instances

[image]

Creating Domino runs with
Geometry nodes -> then I Convert -> Mesh, Separate by Loose Parts, Set Origin to Center and Apply Rigid Body Physics.

The origin rotation values are lost in the process, causing my rigid body "Box" collision to be in the wrong orientation.

Is there a way to grab or keep these rotation values on the mesh for the rigid body sim?

[image]

[image]

Attaching the file, new lines should spawn with a new material index:
[image]

Comment: not as far as i know. Why don't you just use shape mesh instead of box?

Comment: I'm dealing with several thousand dominoes at once and need the simplest collision method for calculation times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup this GN in the mesh object instead of path:

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Make Instances Real* to get this result:

[image]

Remove GN modifier and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> *> Copy Modifiers*:

[image]

You will get all objects aligned as needed, but all the same and use the same material, but you can try to select random objects using *Select Random* and assign different domino models and materials using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.